# Solving Euler #2 through Javascript w/ while loop

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner coder trying to solve a fibonacci question with a while loop, but I'm not confident with using while loops or arrays. This is absolutely terrible coding, but can someone look it over and tell me ways to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">  

/* Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the 
previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will 
be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not 
exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.*/

function math() {
    arr values = [1,2];
    var fib = 0;
    var sum = 2;

    while (values[values.length]<4000000) {
        fib = values[values.length] + values[values.length-1];
        values.push(fib);
        if (fib%2===0) {
            sum += fib;
        }
    }
    alert(sum);
}

</script>  
</head>  

<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    math();
</script> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: So, does it work? If it works - it's good, if it does not - it's not.

Comment: `values[values.length]` will **always be *undefined*** by definition of how arrays work

Comment: @JaromandaX so if arr values = [1,2], values[values.length] does not equal 2?

Comment: correct ... values.length will be 2 ... but the array is zero based index ... so there are values in [0] and [1] ... so, first step, change `values.length - 1` to `values.length - 2` and `values.length` to `values.length - 1` - see if that solves your issue (I haven't checked the rest of your "logic")

Comment: @JaromandaX great, thanks! But so far the code is not running

Comment: check your developer tools console `arr values = [1,2];` should be `var values = [1,2];`

Comment: @JaromandaX oh wow! it worked! thanks so much for your help